# Uniswap )Sushiswap on Arbitrum giving error when trying to sell tokens."execution reverted: UniswapV2: K "Internal JSON-RPC error."

Tags: solidity, hardhat, erc20, uniswap

I am trying to deploy erc20 token with fees, yet even though my hardhat tests passes perfectly, I can only buy those tokens on sushiswap.If I try to sell, I get this error:

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted: UniswapV2: K", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x63D07e5013C39a611bD3D610aE03C79a45E627C7","to":"0xfc506AaA1340b4dedFfd88bE278bEe058952D674","data":"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","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c556e697377617056323a204b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: UniswapV2: K"},"stack":"{\n \"code\": -32603,\n \"message\": \"Internal JSON-RPC error.\",\n \"data\": {\n \"code\": 3,\n \"data\": \"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c556e697377617056323a204b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\n \"message\": \"execution reverted: UniswapV2: K\"\n },\n \"stack\": \"Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.\\n at new n (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:15154)\\n at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:18094)\\n at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:18704)\\n at c (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:1:94385)\\n at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:1:95384\\n at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-2.js:22:58222\"\n}\n at new n (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:15154)\n at s (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:18094)\n at Object.internal (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-1.js:13:18704)\n at c (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:1:94385)\n at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:1:95384\n at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-2.js:22:58222"}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

My _transfer function:

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(from != address(0) && to != address(0) && amount > 0, "Check requirements");
        require(_balances[from] >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        uint256 taxAmount = 0;
        uint256 netAmount = amount;
        if (from != address(this) || to != address(this) || from != owner() || to != owner() || from != address(0)) {
            if (from == uniswapV2Pair) {
                taxAmount = amount * _buyTax / 1000;
            } else if (to == uniswapV2Pair) { if(!openingTrading) 
                {taxAmount = amount * _sellTax / 1000;}
            }
            netAmount = amount - taxAmount;
            if (taxAmount > 0) {
                _balances[from] -= amount;
                _balances[_taxWallet] += taxAmount;
                _balances[to] += netAmount;
                emit Transfer(from, _taxWallet, taxAmount);
                emit Transfer(from, to, netAmount);
            }  else {
                _balances[from] -= amount;
                _balances[to] += amount;
                emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
            }
        } else {
            _balances[from] -= amount;
            _balances[to] += amount;
            emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
        }
    }
```

Hardhat test for selling:

```
it("Tax wallet should receive tokens as fee", async function () {
    // Deposit ETH to contract
    await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: coin.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("100")
    });
    // Open trading
    await coin.connect(owner).openTrading();
    // Define the swap path from WETH to Tokens
    let pathToTokens = [router.WETH(), coin.address];
    // Swap ETH for tokens directly through the Uniswap router
    await router.connect(secondAddr).swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      '0', // accept any amount of Tokens
      pathToTokens,
      secondAddr.address,
      Date.now() + 1000, // Deadline
      {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5"),
        gasPrice: 20e9
      }
    );
    const initialTokenBalance = await coin.balanceOf(secondAddr.address);
    const initialTaxTokenBalance = await coin.balanceOf(owner.address);
    // Approve enough tokens to be transferred
    await coin.connect(secondAddr).approve(uniswapRouterAddr, ethers.utils.parseUnits(initialTokenBalance.toString(), 'wei'));
    // Define the swap path from Tokens to WETH
    let pathToEth = [coin.address, router.WETH()];
    // Perform swap from Tokens back to ETH
    await router.connect(secondAddr).swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
      ethers.utils.parseUnits(initialTokenBalance.toString(), 'wei'),
      0,
      pathToEth,
      secondAddr.address,
      Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20
    );
    const newTaxTokenBalance = await coin.balanceOf(owner.address);
    expect(initialTaxTokenBalance).to.be.below(newTaxTokenBalance);
  });
```

The test returns good results and I don't see anything wrong. Maybe it's because I have $10 worth of eth in arbitrum as liquidity and trying to swap $0.09 worth of tokens? Has anyone had similar problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: If I test a simple _transfer function with no gas, it lets me sell, but if I add sellFee it gives me the same error every time. I think it has something to do with fees, but infura + hardhat testing gives me good results. Tried on ethereum and arbitrum networks